# How to implement SSO with SAS web Report 9.3.

Tags: .net, sas

I have to develop a .net code that call the url of  SAS web Report 9.3 and here I have to skip the first login page of SAS webReport 9.3 how do I implement this? I am new in sas.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you capture SAS user ID in your application? If so, you can pass the user ID to the web application. For example, if you are calling the url via a get method, you can pass user ID and password in the url where you put _USER=USER and _PASSWORD=PASSWORD to authenticate the user.

See the official help for accessing stored processes is here. As far as I know, it applies to web reports too: http://support.sas.com/kb/14/545.html

Note, you may not be able to use pwencode encrypted password. It depends on the setting of your server. I suggest you try both. Also, if your server is on the different domain to the user, you will need to url encode and enclose the user domain too.